# Stream Android screen to video player

Tags: android, qt, adb

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit on my laptop and Android 5.0.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S4 device.
I'm trying to stream my device's screen via adb using following code:
`adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | vlc -`
I have vlc v2.2.4
But it doesn't show anything.

But if I use media player classic, which comes with k-lite mega codec pack v12.3.5 with the following code:
`adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | "C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64\mpc-hc64_nvo.exe" -` it's showing something like my screen, but image is totally broken.

And if I use `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4` to record my devices screen, pull it from device and open it with media player classic, then it video is totally fine. However, vlc can't open even in this case.

What might be the problem? Why I can watch recorded videos, but cannot watch streamed video?

And one more follow-up question. I found adb-server's command to get device's screenshot. It's alternative to the `adb shell screencap` command. I can use that command via QTcpSocket in Qt framework.

However, I couldn't find adb server alternative to `adb shell screenrecord`. In this case I need to use QProcess to run commands and somehow forward output to QMediaPlayer. So far I couldn't succeed in it, cuz as I found `QMediaPlayer::setMedia` accepts `QMediaSource` or `QIODevice`. I found that QProcess is inherited from `QIODevice` and tried to supply it as an argument to `QMediaPlayer:::setMedia`, but my program exited with error code 1. How can I forward `QProcess`'s output to `QMediaPlayer`?

Comment: I answered one of your questions. Please post the rest of your questions separately - keeping one question per post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to support the interactive `adb shell` command the `shell_service` uses [`pty`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pty). It helps to take care of all interactive user input like cursor key presses, etc. But the side effect of using `pty` is that it mangles binary output of the process. This is why capturing the output of `adb shell screenrecord` on the host side results in a corrupted file. Previously the only way to fix that was to post-process the file to remove those extra characters. But some time ago Google has added another version of the `shell` command which does not have the interactive mode and therefore does not need to use the `pty`. They called it `exec-out`.

So in order to capture a file without corruption you should use

```
adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 -
```

Comment: I found that adb exec-out screenrecord stops producing output after some time. Any ideas how to prevent it?

Comment: based the docs: --time-limit time Sets the maximum recording time, in seconds. The default and maximum value is 180 (3 minutes).  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#shellcommands