# How to stream adb shell screenrecord to a windows pc

Tags: android, adb, screen-recording

I want to stream my screen to `vlc` or something like this because the display is broken, I can see nothing on it. I want to do it via `adb` with the command

```
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | vlc --demux h264 -
```

but it says, the command `vlc` is not found. What can I do?

Answer (score -2):

Are you or linux? VLC is not installed. Try

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The ADB command works fine, it's the `| vlc --demux h264` part that's not working.

Comment: hello there thanks for the answer. as the title says, I want to stream it to a windows os

Comment: Then add VLC to your %PATH%

Comment: The problem seems to be in `adb shell`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39578061/3154489

Comment: Thanks @Qrchack. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please consider to upvote it!