# how to redirect adb screenrecord output to pc(windows/linux) storage

Tags: android, linux, shell, ffmpeg, adb

In linux, I use following code to cast android screen to pc, it work well

```
adb shell "screenrecord --time-limit 1 --output-format=h264 -; screenrecord --time-limit 180 --output-format=h264 -" | ffplay -
```

so I think exist way to redirect screenrecord output to pc storage, so I try following code

```
adb shell "screenrecord --time-limit 1 --output-format=h264 -; screenrecord --time-limit 180 --output-format=h264 -" >> /tmp/t.mp4
```

**but the output video file cannot be opened by vlc and google-chrome, how to fix it?**

ffplay is belongs ffmpeg, so I guess exist similar cli in ffmpeg to output input video streaming into video file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39569208/1778421

Answer (score 1):

I find the soluiton, use default ffmpeg, in latest linux mint, it use `avconv` to instead `ffmpeg`, but 2 clis syntax are same, following is my code

```
adb shell "screenrecord --time-limit 1 --output-format=h264 -; screenrecord --time-limit 180 --output-format=h264 -" | avconv -i - /tmp/t.mp4
```